# Binding value for NSTableView, but tooltip gets set as well

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nstableview

I've set up an `NSTableView` in **Interface Builder** to be populated from an `NSArray`. Each value of the array represents one row in the table. The value is bound correctly, but as a side effect, the table cell's tooltip is set to the string representation of the bound object.

In my case, the `NSArray` contains `NSDictionary` objects and the tooltip looks like it could be the `[... description]` output of that dictionary. Very ugly...

I don't want the tooltip to be set at all. I have other tables that have plain NSString values bound to them and they don't have a tooltip set automatically. Is there some Interface Builder magic going on? I tried to start with a blank project - same problem.

I should add that the table cell is a custom implementation of `NSTextFieldCell` that uses an `NSButtonCell` instance to draw an image and a label into the table. The values are retrieved from the dictionary bound as value.

Why is the tooltip set when I only bind the "value" attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Fixed. Here's what happened:

- I used a custom NSTextFieldCell to draw the table cell
- The value was bound do an NSDictionary instance
- The actual cell value was magiaclly set to the string representation of the dictionary. It was not visible, because I used a custom cell.

NSTableView can draw a special tooltip-like window and show the cell's contents if that does not fit into the cell.

- For my custom cell that was the case.

Disabling this can be done by implementing the NSTableViewDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
    shouldShowCellExpansionForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

 return NO;
```

}